# Unable to find seq points for method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger:Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception)'

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xamarin

I am making an android project in Xamarin where I need to perform some task in AsyncTask. But my code is not reaching the RunInBackground(). If I replace RunInBackground() with DoInBackground() I get an error saying- "no suitable method found to override". This is the internal exception I am getting

```
[mono] Unable to find seq points for method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger:Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception)'.
[] * Assertion at /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.8.0-branch/3f1c339b/source/mono/mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:5150, condition `sp' not met
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
Step request failed: Exception of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.VMDisconnectedException' was thrown.
```

What changes I need to do?

Comment: Could you paste in the source code that cause problems? I have similar issues with the XmlSerializer. That message usually means that there is a not supporter/bugged feature in the Mono framework.